# Old pre-0.17 pandas.read_csv behavior of `header=True` for inferring header row?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, header

How did old pre-0.17 versions of pandas `read_csv()` interpret passing a boolean `header=True`/`False` for inferring the header row?

I have CSV data with header:

```
col1;col2;col3
1.0;10.0;100.0
2.0;20.0;200.0
3.0;30.0;300.0
```

## **If read with `header=True`**

i.e. `df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', header=True)`,

that gives the following data-frame:

```
   1.0  10.0  100.0
0    2    20    200
1    3    30    300
```

It means that pandas used the **second row** ("row 1") for column names (the names inferred are '1.0', '10.0' and '100.0').

## **whereas if read with `header=False`**

```
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', header=False)
```

gives the following:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   100
1     2    20   200
2     3    30   300
```

Which means that pandas used the first row ("row 0") as header in spite on the fact that I wrote explicitly that there is no header.

This behaviour is not intuitive to me. Can somebody explain what is happening?

Comment: That CSV data [reads fine in versions 0.17+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html) with `pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep=';')` The question is ancient history and seems to be about old 0.16 behavior from 2015. Passing a boolean [`pd.read_csv(... header=True)` was obsoleted back in 2015](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#changes-to-bool-passed-as-header-in-parsers); today you use int, list of int, or "infer". And by the way, ints start at 0, not 1. So in your case you should say "row 1 was used as headers" not "the second row".

Comment: Anyway these days `pd.read_csv(..., header=None)` will suppress any header. I think the behavior you describe used to be buggy but it was fixed circa 0.17.

Answer (score 16):

You are telling pandas what line is your header line, by passing `False` this evaluates to `0` which is why it reads in the first line as the header as expected, when you pass `True` it evaluates to `1` so it reads the second line, if you passed `None` then it thinks there is no header row and will auto generated ordinal values.

```
In [17]:    
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""col1;col2;col3
1.0;10.0;100.0
2.0;20.0;200.0
3.0;30.0;300.0"""
print('False:\n', pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=False))
print('\nTrue:\n', pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=True))
print('\nNone:\n', pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=None))

False:
    col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   100
1     2    20   200
2     3    30   300

True:
    1.0  10.0  100.0
0    2    20    200
1    3    30    300

None:
       0     1      2
0  col1  col2   col3
1   1.0  10.0  100.0
2   2.0  20.0  200.0
3   3.0  30.0  300.0
```

**UPDATE**

Since version `0.17.0` this will now raise a [`TypeError`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-bool-passed-as-header-in-parsers)

Comment: you may use `header=0` instead of `header=True` for Pandas version higher than 0.17.0 to specify the first row as the header.